# Member registration emails not sending

Tags: members

I'm finding that an installation is not sending email notifications to members once the account has been changed from pending. Is there an option I need to check to send the notification? I thought it was sent automatically. The email to notify admin that someone has registered is being sent and received.

Comment: What version of EE?

Comment: Hi, it's version 2.5.3. It's been working OK for quite a while, but just suddenly stopped.

Comment: Did you check your server is working with PHP mailer? If not, you should try to use SMTP

Comment: It's using PHP mailer, which works OK for everything else.